# How to add "you added this" bellow the product in the collection SHOPIFY

Tags: javascript, web, shopify, store

I'm sorry for this simple quistion but I really got a headache !

I need to add "You added this item" text bellow the product After adding to cart.

for example: I have a list of fruits .. when the client add 5 kilos from apple then back to the home page to check the other fruits .. He notice that he bought the apple product by adding "You added this item" text bellow the price.
[image]

thanks

Comment: You will need some Javascript logic with AJAX here, but in order to help you we need to see what have you tried on your own (in code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the following code in a place where the `product` object is available on the homepage (or anywhere else).

```
{%- assign productCartItems = cart.items | where: "product_id", product.id | size -%}
{%- if productCartItems > 0 -%}
  You added this item
{%- endif -%}
```